# Macintosh HD not using entire drive

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, ssd

I have a 2016 15" macbook pro with a 256gb ssd. Only 122gb are used by MacOS. How do I get MacOS to use the entire drive? I believe this happened because of a botched bootcamp uninstall. Disk utility shows the following:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's the output from `diskutil list`

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         122.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +122.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            104.0 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.7 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Recommendation: make sure you have a good backup of anything important before proceeding. We get way to many questions here from people whose drive format got messed up while trying to fix weird partitioning issues. Hopefully you can fix this cleanly, and won't need a backup; but I wouldn't depend on it.

Comment: Thank you! I have made a backup. As a matter of fact I have purchased a new laptop and have already restored it. No need for the data or anything on this one. I’m trying to factory reset it and give it to a sibling of mine. I was going to format the drive and reinstall MacOS but I wasn’t sure if that would fix this issue. I wanted to fix the drive and then go through with those steps. I may be wrong though. Should I just go ahead and reinstall macOS?

Comment: In that case, I'd just erase the drive (note: the entire drive, not just the volume), and reinstall from scratch. BUT first you should disassociate the Mac from your iCloud/iTunes/etc account, see [Apple Support Document HT201065](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065). Then start up from Internet Recovery (restart, hold Command-Option-R until you see the Apple logo; see [HT204904](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)), erase the entire disk ([HT208496](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496)), and reinstall clean.

Comment: Another option is to download the OS installer and create a bootable installer on a flash drive ([HT201372](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)), then use that instead of Internet Recovery. Frankly, if I was doing it, this the method I'd pick; it's more work, but having all the necessary tools/installers/etc available locally before I start gives me the warm fuzzies.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I think I've resolved this. I booted into recovery mode and ran first aid on the container (not the disk, not the volume). Then i logged back in and ran this: `diskutil apfs resizeContainer /dev/disk1 0`

Comment: Cool! I'd still do the disassociate/erase/reinstall process, but if the container's fixed you only need to erase the volume(s), and you can do the erase/reinstall from the local Recovery volume (start with just Command-R), which'll be faster than Internet Recovery.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I followed that process and got it reset. Everything seems to have gone smoothly. I appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

I just needed to resize the container (because apparently that's a simple thing to do). I first had to restart into recovery mode and run firstaid on the container. I ran it on all 3 of the drive, the container, and the volume to be safe, but I'm certain only the run on the container did anything. Then I restarted and logged in and in a terminal ran the following:

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer /dev/disk1 0
```